# MQTT connection breaks upon 1000 simultaneous requests

Tags: java

I am Using Amazon Mq as my Mqtt broker and when around 1000 requests are received simultaneously the mqtt broker breaks and disconnects. Can Anyone tell me how to use Amazon Mq as my broker & simultaneously solve the scaling problem also.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you have created ActiveMQ as a `singleton class`. Right?

-For producing a message, you create an instance of PooledConnectionFactory like

```
-------//some code here
ActiveMQConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory(MQTT_END_POINT);
    connectionFactory.setUserName();
    connectionFactory.setPassword();
    PooledConnectionFactory pooledConnectionFactory = getActiveMQInstance().configurePooledConnectionFactory(activeMQConnectionFactory);
-------
```

This pooledConnectionFactory is used to create a `connection then session and then destination` is entered (as mentioned on AmazonMQ documentation). You send the message using `MessageProducer` object and close the `MessageProducer, session and connection`

-For consumption, there will be an always-alive-listener that is always ready for message to arrive. The consumer part, it follows the same process like `consumerConnection, then session and then destination queue to listen on.`
As far as I remember, this part is also mentioned in amazonMQ documentation.

There is one problem that the connection to broker is lost for consumer sometimes, (since producer reopens the connections, produces and closes, it is not observed in it). Remember, you will have to reestablish the connection for consumer.

If there is any variance from the above approach please mention. Also, add your amazonMQ broker picture showing the connection, queue, active consumers.
Just out of curiosity, what are the maximum connections you have set for the PooledConnectionFactory?